# Assign lowest record ID with Outer Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (ID int, EmployeeIdentifier varchar(100),ManagerIdentifier varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE EmployeeManager (ID int, EmployeeID varchar(100))

INSERT Employee
VALUES
(1,'apple','apple'),
(2,'banana','apple'),
(3,'citrus','apple'),
(4,'grape','grape'),
(5,'grape','grape'),
(6,'grape','grape')

INSERT EmployeeManager
VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,4),
(5,5),
(6,5)
```

For `Employee.ID IN (1,2,3)`, records in `EmployeeManager` look fine.
But in `Employee.ID IN (4,5,6)` we can see many duplicates. We are not allowed to delete any records from `Employee` table. But we are free to assign `EmpoyeeManager.EmployeeID` value. Since there is only one Actual record for `Grape` and the rest is duplicate, I want to assign `EmpoyeeManager.EmployeeID` to a minimum value `Employee.ID` from all duplicated grape records in `Employee` table, aka to 4.

I have this query,

```
UPDATE d SET EmployeeID = l.ID
FROM dbo.EmployeeManager d
INNER JOIN Employee s on d.ID=s.ID
OUTER APPLY (
    
                SELECT  ID
                FROM  Employee l 
                WHERE s.ManagerIdentifier=l.EmployeeIdentifier
) l
WHERE 
EXISTS (
                SELECT d.EmployeeID
                EXCEPT
                SELECT l.ID
            )
```

If you keep running it you will see that `EmployeeManager.EmployeeID` values for ID (4,5,6) will keep changing.
How I can I update above update statement to assign to the lowest value of `Employee.ID` for all EmployeeManager.ID (4,5,6), aka to 4?

We are not allowed to run one time fix script, because corrupted data to above table can keep coming.

Desired output after running above update statement should be

[image]

Comment: For clarity please show, sample table and desired results in tabular form.

Comment: Please don't use images for data... use formatted, tabular, text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY` in the subquery to pick out a specific row**

```sql
UPDATE d SET EmployeeID = l.ID
FROM dbo.EmployeeManager d
INNER JOIN Employee s on d.ID=s.ID
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (1) ID
                FROM  Employee l 
                WHERE s.ManagerIdentifier = l.EmployeeIdentifier
                ORDER BY ID
) l
WHERE 
EXISTS (
                SELECT d.EmployeeID
                EXCEPT
                SELECT l.ID
            )
```

- You appear to have a normalization issue, as the `Manager` is defined in two places
- I suggest you use better aliases for your tables, they are not very memorable
- You can change your `OUTER` to `CROSS`, and then you can use a standard `<>` instead of the `EXISTS/EXCEPT`

```sql
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (1) ID
                FROM  Employee l 
                WHERE s.ManagerIdentifier = l.EmployeeIdentifier
                ORDER BY ID
) l
WHERE d.EmployeeID <> l.ID
```

Comment: top(1) might not work, because condition in where clause might eliminate that top(1) entry

Comment: It's *supposed* to eliminate it, because you don't want to update it when the value is the same. The `WHERE` is basically just saying `d.EmployeeID <> l.ID` and therefore filtering out rows that are already correct

Comment: sorry, I got confused initially with top(1). I got right though initially. now is more clear. I know normalization isn't the best, i can't change anything there.